# Split a tuple into different files

Tags: python, file, parsing, url-rewriting, tuples

I have a list of URL's that I would like to split up on a tuple with certain chars, such as `'p'` or `'blog'` (the full tuple looks like this: `[('p', '958')][('blog', '3')][('p', '2512')]`). I would like to split and write these into separate, appropriately named files(`p_file.txt`, `blog_file.txt`, etc). I, however, am stuck. I have been trying multiple ways but I have not been having any success. Would appreciate any help.

```
def parse_file():
    infile = open("URLlist.txt", 'r')
    outfile = open("newfile4.txt", 'w')
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        url = parse_qsl(urlparse(line)[4])
        if url:
            print url
parse_file()
```

Comment: Tuples in python are immutable. You need convert the tuple into a list and then split.

Comment: The file that I am reading is a list or URL's.

Answer (score 1):

To get all 'p' tuples in the list, just iterate over to find the match. List comprehensions make this easy.

```
urls = ( [('p', '958')],[('blog', '3')],[('p', '2512')])
p_names = [ p_tuple  for url in urls for p_tuple in url if 'p' in p_tuple ]
```

p_name is now a list with 'p' tuples.